# Deploy a windows service without Installshield

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-services, installshield

Is it possible to deploy a windows service without going through Installshield?  I have a very basic service which simply probes a database, and wish to deploy it on a server.

I tried using Installsheild LE, but get error 1001 on install, which is hard to troubleshoot, and anyhow Installshield feels like overkill in this case... is there a way can just install the service direct by command line or other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your service has an [Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer(v=vs.110).aspx) class then, you can install it from command line with [installutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.ServiceProcess;

    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class ServiceInstaller : Installer
    {
        public ServiceInstaller()
        {
            ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

            //# Service Account Information
            serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.User;
            serviceProcessInstaller.Username = "";
            serviceProcessInstaller.Password = "";

            //# Service Information
            serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "Service name"
            serviceInstaller.Description = "Service description"
            serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;

            //# This must be identical to the WindowsService.ServiceBase name
            //# set in the constructor of WindowsService.cs
            serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "Service Name";

            this.Installers.Add(serviceProcessInstaller);
            this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

However, there are options, from best to worst:

1. There are other tools for writing installers out there. Eg. the full version of install Shield or [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) (which MS created, and is used for the Visual Studio installer).
2. You could use [`installUtil`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) having included a type derived from [`ServiceInstaller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your assembly. (See *[How to: Install and Uninstall Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*.)
3. You can manually edit the registry.

#3 Is seriously easy to mess up, and won't help you with the event logging and performance counters you should be including.<sup>1</sup> #2 is best in development, and will set up event logs and performance counters as well (remember you'll need to elevate to install things, and to attach a debugger to the service when running as a service).

Using a real installer (#1) is best in test (staging) and production environments.

---

<sup>1</sup> When you get asked why it isn't working, you'll want to be able to work out what's going on (or not).

Answer (score 0):

[Building and Deploying a Windows Service using IsWiX](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJxU47_zqbw)

The above is a short video I made showing how to use WiX / IsWiX to generate a very clean MSI for installing a service.  It's really easy, fast, elegant and free.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line tool **sc.exe** to create and configure a windows service (basically insert the config into registry), assuming you have already deployed the built .exe to disk somewhere on your server.

http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/251192